# Exporting lightmaps to another project - Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, import, export, light, lightning

We are currently working on various project as a team. As such, we often have to transfer scenes and such from one project to another. However, we have a problem concerning the lightmaps.

When I take my scene, make a package out of it all (lightmaps included) and then export, when I import in the other project, the lightmaps are there, (as in, in the "Lightning" window, they are present and loaded) but they just don't apply on the scene. It's like they aren't here at all.

And so we have to rebake everything, which makes us lose hours of work. (And as the graphic guy, it frustrates me that I have to wait two times)

Any tips on how to deal with this issue ?

Thanks !

Comment: It's not clear what environment/language/tool you're working with.  Update your tags and title to attract experts in the area.

Comment: Oh indeed ! Thanks, I added that !

Comment: Its probable that you're missing one of the metadata files associated with connecting the two. I only played with baked lighting a couple years ago fixing a problem I only vaguely recall. Try this: bring over the files as normal. Copy the project. Open the original, recompile the lightmaps, close the project.  Get a file-diff utility like Beyond Compare, compare the project with the backup copy. What changed? Try copying over those other changed files. Fiddle with what you copy and don't (make some intelligent guesses) until you find the missing piece.

Comment: Dealing with this now - any answers?